# Como agregar una barra de progreso con react js cada vez que se dirección a una nueva ruta de un nuevo componente usando react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router-dom

lo que sucede es que estoy usando react router en un proyecto en el cual estoy usando react js, entonces quiero que aparezca un barra de progreso cada vez que el usuario se encuentre en una ruta distinta,debo de mencionar que la barra de progreso pues debe completarse una vez que el componente termine de renderizarse, algo muy similar como lo hace o hacia YouTube

Comment: Quizás esto te pueda ayudar https://gist.github.com/shelldandy/02ad1a9f8b5b86d1b2e4dd26a11967b2

Comment: recuerda que debes instalar `nprogress` en tu proyecto con el siguiente comando `npm i nprogress`